# Combing similar steps that span multiple periods

Tags: t-sql

The problem I am having is there is a set of data that is tracking tasks as they move through various stages of their life cycle. At the most basic level Open, worked on and then closed. The problem I have is, the system often tags the ticket multiple days with the same status. So rather than seeing it as Open Monday and Worked on Friday. You may see Open Monday, Open Wednesday, or worse Open Monday Worked on Tuesday Open Wednesday. This is preventing me from doing a simple group by status and ranking by begin date.

What I am really asking for help on is collapsing the duplicates.  I have made some sample data below. If you look at the Status_Name Approved you will see it has very many occurrences which is OK, but 2 of them are 2022-02-17 and 2022-02-18 overlap. They should really be a single line. I eventually I am going to calculate the average time in each state, and I want to collapse anywhere the Status_name repeats. I tried to do it in a recursive CTE but it didn't work. So this like would be BEG_DT 2022-02-17 end 2022-06-30

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TEMP 
CREATE TABLE #TEMP (PRODUCT VARCHAR(30), STATUS_NAME VARCHAR(30), BEG_DT DATE,END_DT DATE)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES
('Chevy1','Scoping','2021-08-23','2021-11-18')
,('Chevy1','Qualified','2021-11-25','2022-01-25')
,('Chevy1','Approved','2022-01-25','2022-02-17')
,('Chevy1','Completed','2022-02-17','2022-02-17')
,('Chevy1','Approved','2022-02-17','2022-02-18')
,('Chevy1','Approved','2022-02-18','2022-06-30')
,('Chevy1','Deferred','2022-06-30','2023-03-16')
,('Chevy1','Approved','2023-03-16',null)    
;
WITH CALC AS (
SELECT Product
        ,Status_Name
        ,BEG_DT
        ,END_DT
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PRODUCT ORDER BY BEG_DT) RNB
FROM #TEMP
)
,Rec_CALC as (
SELECT Product
        ,Status_Name
        ,BEG_DT
        ,END_DT
        ,CAST(RNB AS INT) AS RNB
FROM CALC

UNION ALL 

SELECT t2.Product
        ,t2.Status_Name
        ,t2.BEG_DT
        ,t2.END_DT
        ,CAST(0 AS INT)
FROM CALC c
JOIN Rec_CALC t2
on c.PRODUCT = t2.PRODUCT
and c.STATUS_NAME = t2.STATUS_NAME
and CAST(c.RNB AS INT) = CAST(t2.RNB-1 AS INT)
)
```

Comment: what is the expected result for the samples that you provided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a variation of the *Gaps and Islands* problem.

The general solution is to group the similar rows having contiguous dates (`Beg_Dt` = prior `End_dt`) by (1) marking rows that are *not* a continuation of the prior record and then (2) calculating a running sum of that flag. That sum becomes the group number used to identify rows to be grouped and combined.

The trick is selecting the correct partitioning ordering columns. The "Completed" row with the same beging/end dates among otherwise contiguous "Approved" rows was a bit tricky. The solution was to use `OVER(PARTITION BY Product ORDER BY Beg_Dt, End_Dt)` as  the windowing criteria and checking both the dates and `Status_Name` to identify the discontinuities (gaps).

Once the group numbers are calculated, it then just becomes a matter of combining the grouped rows, selecting the minimum Beg_Dt and maximum End_Dt as the combined date range.

Something like

```
SELECT
    Product,
    Status_Name,
    MIN(Beg_Dt) AS Beg_Dt,
    MAX(End_Dt) AS End_Dt,
    COUNT(*) AS NumCombined
FROM (
    SELECT
       *,
       SUM(IsGap) OVER(PARTITION BY Product ORDER BY Beg_Dt, End_Dt) AS Grp
    FROM (
        SELECT
           *,
           CASE WHEN Beg_Dt = LAG(End_Dt)
                  OVER(PARTITION BY Product ORDER BY Beg_Dt, End_Dt)
              AND Status_Name = LAG(Status_Name)
                  OVER(PARTITION BY Product ORDER BY Beg_Dt, End_Dt)
              THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS IsGap
        FROM #TEMP
    ) G
) G
GROUP BY Product, Status_Name, Grp
ORDER BY Product, Beg_Dt, End_Dt;
```

Results:

| Product | Status_Name | Beg_Dt | End_Dt | NumCombined |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Chevy1 | Scoping | 2021-08-23 | 2021-11-18 | 1 |
| Chevy1 | Qualified | 2021-11-25 | 2022-01-25 | 1 |
| Chevy1 | Approved | 2022-01-25 | 2022-02-17 | 1 |
| Chevy1 | Completed | 2022-02-17 | 2022-02-17 | 1 |
| Chevy1 | Approved | 2022-02-17 | 2022-06-30 | 2 |
| Chevy1 | Deferred | 2022-06-30 | 2023-03-16 | 1 |
| Chevy1 | Approved | 2023-03-16 | null | 1 |

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/UAElitdj).

Comment: Thanks so much. I used this with the slight modification to make the CTEs instead of embedded queries, but it works just as you show. Thanks.